# unix - awk unexpected behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have the below code in a bash file called 'findError.sh':

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
formatindicator="\"|\""
echo "$formatindicator"
formatarg="\$1"
echo "$formatarg"
count=`awk -F$formatindicator '{print $formatarg}' $filename | perl -ane '{ if(m/ERROR/) { print } }' | wc -l `
command="awk -F$formatindicator '{print $formatarg}' $filename | perl -ane '{ if(m/ERROR/) { print } }' | wc -l"
echo $command
echo $count
```

I then run it at  the command line like so:
sh findError.sh test.dat

But It gives me a different count than running the command that was echoed?? How is this possible?

ie
The $command that is echoed back is:

```
awk -F"|" '{print $1}' test.dat | perl -ane '{ if(m/ERROR/) { print } }' | wc -l
```

But the $count that is echoed back is:

```
3
```

However if I just run this one line below at the command line (not through the script) - the result is 0:

```
awk -F"|" '{print $1}' test.dat | perl -ane '{ if(m/ERROR/) { print } }' | wc -l
```

Sample input file (test.dat):

```
sid|storeNo|latitude|longitude
2|1|-28.03720000
9|2
10
jgn352|1|-28.03ERROR720000
9|2|fdERRORkjhn422-405
0000543210|gfERRORdjk39
```

Notes: Using SunOS with bash version 4.0.17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're being too careful with your quotes around the format delimiter.

When you type:

```
awk -F"|" ...
```

The program (`awk`) sees `-F|` as its first argument; the shell strips the double quotes.

When you have:

```
formatindicator="\"|\""
echo "$formatindicator"
formatarg="\$1"
echo "$formatarg"
count=`awk -F$formatindicator ...`
```

You have preserved the double quotes in `$formatindicator` and therefore `awk` sees `-F"|"` as the delimiter, and uses the double quote as the delimiter.

Use:

```
formatindicator="|"
echo "$formatindicator"
formatarg="\$1"
echo "$formatarg"
count=`awk -F"$formatindicator" ...`
```

The difference is that the shell strips the quotes off `-F"$formatindicator"` but doesn't do that when `$formatindicator` itself contains the double quotes.

(NB: edited to retain back-quotes instead of the `$(...)` notation that is (a) preferred and (b) was used in the first version of this answer.  The `$(...)` notation was not recognized by the SunOS `/bin/sh` which was, I believe, being used to execute the script. Both `bash` and `ksh` recognize the `$(...)` notation, but the basic Bourne shell, `/bin/sh`, on Solaris 10 (SunOS 5.10) and earlier (I've not laid hands on Solaris 11) does not recognize `$(...)`.)

I note that any of `perl`, `awk` or `grep` could be used to find the count of the error lines on its own, so the triplet of `awk` piped to `perl` piped to `wc` is not very efficient.

```
awk -F"|" '$1 ~ /ERROR/ { count++ } END { print count }' $filename

grep -c ERROR $filename                # simple
grep -c '^[^|]*ERROR[^|]*|' $filename  # accurate

perl -anF"|" -e '$count++ if $F[0] =~ m/ERROR/; END { print "$count\n"; }' $filename
```

It's Perl, so [TMTOWTDI](http://catb.org/jargon/html/T/TMTOWTDI.html); take your pick...

---

#### Side discussion

In the comments, we have concerns over how various parts of the script are being interpreted.

```
formatindicator="|"
formatarg="\$1"

count=`awk -F$formatindicator '{print $formatarg}' $filename | perl -ane '{ if(m/ERROR/) { print } }' | wc -l `
```

Let's simplify this to (using part of my main answer):

```
count=`awk -F"$formatindicator" '{print $formatarg}' $filename`
```

The intention is to have the delimiter specified on the command line (which happens successfully) via the `-F` option.  The issue, I expect, is "why does `$formatarg` get expanded inside single quotes?".  And the answer is "Does it?".  I think not.  So, what is happening, is that `awk` is seeing the script `{print $formatarg}`.  Since `formatarg` is not assigned any value, it is equivalent to 0, so the script prints `$0`, which is the entire input line.  Perl is quite happy to echo the line if it matches ERROR anywhere on the line, and `wc` couldn't care less about what's in the lines, so the result is approximately what was expected.  The only time there'd be a discrepancy is when the line from `$filename` contains ERROR in other than the first pipe-delimited field.  That would be counted by the script where it should not.

Comment: Not using `bash` like you claimed - this is being run with the SunOS `/bin/sh` which is not `bash` and does not recognize `$( ... )` as an alternative to using back-quotes.  Revert to using back-quotes instead.

Comment: But `awk` won't take external variables like that, will it? Don't we have to assign `the external variables` in `awk` via `-v` route?

Comment: @JaypalSingh Because he is using the `-F` option rather than the awk variable `FS`, `$formatindicator` will be expanded by the shell.  In fact you can still have the shell expand variables inside an awk script as long as that variable isn't within single-quotes. However, using double quotes around an awk script will require you to escape out just about everything else that is special to the shell, this is why awk allows for `-v`.  Another, and my preferred way, is to put the variables at the end as in `var="|";awk '{print}' RS="$var"`.

Comment: @JaypalSingh: I don't see where external variables come into the picture.  I'm using the `awk` command line option to set the field delimiter; that's all.  I'm not even thinking about setting any variables.

Comment: True but the `Field delimiter` gets the value from a `variable($formatindicator)` which is defined outside `awk`. I'm confused. I always thought if awk needs to get values from variables defined outside it's scope, it needs to use the `-v option` and assign the variable to it's internal variable.

Comment: Thanks for the udpate Jon, I am surprised OP didn't see any error on the `awk` line because `awk` cannot handle anything other than a number which is prefixed with a `$` sign in the `action body`.

Comment: Print the last field on each line: `awk '{print $NF}'`.  NF is a variable name; `$NF` is the field with the number stored in `NF` (which is the variable in `awk`; `awk != perl` and `awk` variables are not prefixed with the `$`).

Comment: Right I mean't `awk` will throw error when something like this is used `'{print $formatarg}'`

Comment: Your example is isomorphic with mine; the only difference is that NF is not usually 0 whereas `formatarg` is an uninitialized variable and therefore 0.

Comment: True, but it won't be if we use `-v fa="$formatarg"` and use `fa` instead of `$formatarg` in the action body. Sorry to be pushy, just hoping to learn something from you. So think of me as your apprentice. :)

Comment: OK; yes, you could assign to the variables in the way described, though the value of `$formatarg` in the shell would have be just `1` for it to work correctly (written as `'{print $fa}'` in the `awk` script).  The `-v var=value` notation is required by POSIX.  Classically, the `-v` was not necessary and just `var=value` was sufficient.

Comment: Yea, I agree that `$formatarg` should be `1` instead of `$1`. Thanks so much Jon, really appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with using external variables in `awk`. If you wish to use external variables in `awk` then define a variable in the `awk` one-liner using `-v` option and `variable name` and assign your `external variable` to it. So

The line -

```
count=`awk -F$formatindicator '{print $formatarg}' $filename | perl -ane '{ if(m/ERROR/) { print } }' | wc -l `
```

should be -

```
count=`awk -v fi="$formatindicator" -v fa="$formatarg" 'BEGIN {FS=fi}{print fa}' "$1" | perl -ane '{ if(m/ERROR/) { print } }' | wc -l `
```

**Update:**

As stated in the comments, the `$formatarg` contains the value `$1`. What you need to do is store just `1` and then pass it as -

```
count=`awk -v fi=$formatindicator -v fa="$formatarg" 'BEGIN {FS=fi}{print $fa}' "$1" | perl -ane '{ if(m/ERROR/) { print } }' | wc -l

[jaypal:~/Temp] echo $formatindicator
|
[jaypal:~/Temp] echo $formatarg
1
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v fi="$formatindicator" -v fa="$formatarg" 'BEGIN {FS=fi}{print $fa}' data.file
sid
2
9
10
jgn352
9
0000543210
```

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
formatindicator="|"
echo "$formatindicator"
formatarg="1"
echo "$formatarg"
count=`awk -v fa="$formatarg" -v fi="$formatindicator" 'BEGIN{FS=fi}{print $fa}' $filename | perl -ane '{ if(m/ERROR/) { print } }' | wc -l `
command="awk -F$formatindicator '{print $formatarg}' $filename | perl -ane '{ if(m/ERROR/) { print } }' | wc -l"
echo $command
echo $count
```

Comment: Shouldn't `'{print fa}'` be `'{print $fa}'`?

Comment: Well ya but then format argument variable should be stored as 1 and not $1.